# Why is 一緒に needed when it's already clear two people will be together?

Tags: usage, set-phrases

A father is talking to his kid about their plans tomorrow and says,

> けんしんくん、お父さんと一緒に買いに行きましょうか？

Why not:

> けんしんくん、お父さんと買いに行きましょうか？

(The sentence is supposed to say, "Kenshin, would you like to go to shopping with dad?" Obviously, not a one-to-one translation)

Aren't both sentences the same? I can't see the second sentence **not** relaying the idea of "together". So what does the 一緒に do exactly? It seems, to me, that the sentence doesn't really need it.

Comment: Are you sure the father talked to his child in polite form? Is that the royal family or something?

Comment: Does being royal or commoner have anything to do with 一緒に? lol.

Comment: Of course not. It may have something to do with using politeness to the own child.

Comment: It's an example sentence, sawa. I didn't realize the politeness level would distract from the question.

Comment: Why is `together` "needed" in the English expression `go shopping together with dad` when you can say `go shopping with dad`?

Comment: Actually it's not needed. Most english speakers would say: "go shopping with dad". At least in America.

Comment: I agree. That is why it is in double quotation. And the same is for Japanese. 一緒に is not needed (which is already obvious from your other Japanese example). At least in Japan.

Answer (score 2):

At the coffee shop after practice, 行こうか is a perfectly good sentence if the highest ranking person says it. Everyone will get up and leave. In other situations, *do you want to go home* is very different from *do you want to go home with me.* Japanese can drop the *you*, but still needs the 一緒 (but not the me/us/them). I remember hearing a lot of 一緒に without names or pronouns. I know this is an example sentence, but I wonder if since 一緒に is so often required in this kind of question, it isn't automatically used and then names are added for emphasis. By 'then added', I mean some kind of mental process that assembles the sentence before speaking, not final word order.

Answer (score 0):

Why is `together` "needed" in the English expression

> go shopping together with dad

when you can say

> go shopping with dad

Doesn't the latter already convey the idea of "together"?

Comment: Actually it's not needed. Most english speakers would say: "go shopping with dad". At least in America.

Comment: I agree. That is why it is in double quotation. And the same is for Japanese. 一緒に is not needed (which is already obvious from your other Japanese example). At least in Japan.

Comment: Ahhh. Well the times that I've heard any sentence about two people doing something, と一緒に was used. So I thought it was common to use it as opposed to omitting it.

Comment: 一緒に may not be compulsary but would be used most of the time.

Comment: My native speaker intuition says that "Go shopping together with dad" is *much* less natural than "お父さんと一緒に買い物に行く". "Needed" may not be the correct word but I think that it is quite reasonable to wonder what underlies the fact that "一緒に" appears much more often in Japanese than "together" does in English, when both are equally "unnecessary" from a pure meaning standpoint. Not because the Japanese way is "illogical" or anything, but simply because there must be a reason for the difference and that reason is probably interesting.

Comment: I agree with Matt - using 一緒に in this kind of situation is much more natural than using "together" in English. To equate them, much like equating most things in the Japanese language with a single, clear-cut English counterpart, is misleading at best. Answer could also be interpreted as smart-ass, but I'm sure that's not the way it was intended...

Comment: @Matt, @ジョン Is it always unnatural to use `together` with `with` not necessarily consecutively, or is there any natural occasion?

Comment: @sawa Ironically I know even less about the formal description of English grammar than Japanese, but my subjective feeling is that while "with my dad" functions as a simple (VP-level) adverb, "together with my dad" is more like a sentence-level adverb, or perhaps even attached to the noun. So "with my dad" simply indicates that the action was performed along with "my dad", but "together with my dad" is more marked and may suggest that the addition of "my dad" is unexpected.

Comment: (Incidentally I suspect that a similar (structural) explanation may hold for the difference between と and と一緒に, so the phenomenon may come down to which kind of adverbial modifier is "preferred" or "default" in a given language/situation.)

Comment: @Matt I do not think "together with my dad" is a constituent. "go shopping together" is a constituent, and "with my dad" is adjoining to it. This means "together" is a VP adverb.

Comment: @sawa But in this situation, "go shopping together" cannot be a constituent, because the subject is singular ("I"). (OTOH, "My dad and I went shopping together" and "I went shopping with my dad" are both totally natural.) Perhaps this is the problem: because the non-plural subject does not allow "go shopping together" as a constituent, "together with my dad" is reanalyzed as a semi-independent sentence-level adverbial phrase, and this feels awkward.

Comment: @sawa Rephrasing to avoid that problem, "My mum and I went shopping together with my dad" also feels a bit unnatural (not ungrammatical), but "My mum and I went shopping with my dad" does not. So maybe even when "together" *could* function as a VP adverb, the combination of "together" and "with X" feels unnatural for semantic reasons (e.g. "Together" already describes the makeup and relationship of the participant group, which may "disallow" adding another participant using "with X"), and this motivates a reanalysis as "together with X", which is awkward.

Comment: @Matt Then what about this: `the family went shopping with each other` vs `the family went shopping together with each other`.

Comment: @sawa I find both of those unnatural, but I think the verb has something to do with it too: "The kids fought w.o.t." (ok), "The kids fought t." (not ok), "The kids fought t. w.o.t." (not ok); but, "The kids played w.o.t." (ok), "The kids played t." (ok), "The kids played t. w.o.t." (not ok); but, "The kids worked t. w.o.t." (redundant, but more natural than "went shopping t. w.o.t.", and "worked together" feels like a constituent)

Answer (score 0):

"一緒に" gives an impression that Kenshin and his father do shopping together all the way through. Even if you don't say "一緒に", the sentence would mean the same basically.

However, it would also be taken as "I would go shopping with you. You drive, and drop me at the entrance of the department, you do shopping for your own, I do mine. Let's get back together at the entrance when we both finish shopping." ...Because you didn't mention "together" for shopping.

I guess this explanation would work the same in other languages through.

Answer (score 0):

> Aren't both sentences the same?

Probably not sentimentally.
There's much more of a bond in the use of 一緒に.

Also, I think that it expresses ((with-me go) shopping) more than (go (with-me shopping)).

> I can't see the second sentence not relaying the idea of "together". So what does the 一緒に do exactly? It seems, to me, that the sentence doesn't really need it.

In many languages, there are words that are often used, but are not necessary, or not even meaningful. In this case, it is meaningful, but not necessary. Sometimes, it's just a habit. Or some improper sentence that goes uncorrected for it's perfectly understood.
Just to tease you more, consider the sentence "約10人ぐらいいました", which means "there are approximately around 10 people." Bad English, very natural Japanese…

The notion of "need" you have needs to be loosened :)